# Hadoop 2.2.0 init datanode failed in mac osx

Tags: macos, hadoop

I try to start hadoop 2.2.0 offical release in my mac osx(10.9).
But it's failed to start datanode. Please refer to below error message:

```
2013-11-05 00:29:45,381 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Initialization failed for block pool Block pool BP-1261650833-192.168.5.102-1383580328383 (storage id DS-195316454-192.168.5.102-50010-1383582585181) service to ning/192.168.5.102:9010
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.protocol.DisallowedDatanodeException): Datanode denied communication with namenode: DatanodeRegistration(0.0.0.0, storageID=DS-195316454-192.168.5.102-50010-1383582585181, infoPort=50075, ipcPort=50020, storageInfo=lv=-47;cid=CID-e22d5b33-0f57-47bb-ae7f-73f7393833b7;nsid=1896158194;c=0)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.DatanodeManager.registerDatanode(DatanodeManager.java:739)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.registerDatanode(FSNamesystem.java:3929)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.registerDatanode(NameNodeRpcServer.java:948)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.registerDatanode(DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.DatanodeProtocolProtos$DatanodeProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(DatanodeProtocolProtos.java:24079)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:585)
```

Comment: Such situation can happen on stale cluster id in datanode dirs.
Try delete datanode data dirs and restart datanode